# How do I create a Jquery datepicker dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For my app, I'm trying to add a Jquery Datepicker after a certain event (for this example, let's just say when the page loads).

I'm currently trying to do something like this:

```
    var mealControl = new MealControl();
    $(document).ready(function(){
            mealControl.createMealForm();
        }); //document.ready

    function MealControl() { 
                this.createMealForm = function(){
                        var currentDate = new Date();
                        var prettyCurrentDate = currentDate.getFullYear() + '/' + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + currentDate.getDate();
                        var innerHtml = "<p>Creating meal item data input here</p>" +
                            "<div>Title:<input id=\"mealTitle\" type=\"text\" align=\"center\" width=\"50\" class=\"ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset\" />" +
                            "<br></div>" + 
                            "<div class=\"ui-input-datebox ui-shadow-inset ui-corner-all ui-body-c\">" +
                            "<div class=\"ui-input-datebox ui-shadow-inset ui-corner-all ui-body-c\">" +
                            "<input data-options=\"{'mode':'calbox','calHighPicked':false, 'calHighToday':true, 'calHighPicked': false}\" data-role=\"datebox\"id=\"datePicker\" value=\"Enter consumption date here\" type=\"text\" align=\"center\" class=\"ui-input-text ui-body-c\"/>" +
                            "<a href=\"#\" class=\"ui-input-clear ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow\" title=\"date picker\" data-theme=\"c\" style=\"vertical-align: middle; float: right; \">" +
                            "<span class=\"ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all\" aria-hidden=\"true\">" +
                            "<span class=\"ui-btn-text\">date picker</span>" +
                            "<span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-grid ui-icon-shadow\"></span></span></a>"
                            "</div>"
                        $("#contentDiv").html(innerHtml);
                    } //createMealForm
```

When I do it this way, the button that should bring up the date picker does not do anything.  However, if I put all of those elements right into my

```
<div data-role="content" id="contentDiv" class="ui-content" role="main">
```

the button works just fine.  I'm completely stumped by this behaviour and any help would be much appreciated.

Also, I've read in other places it should be as simple as

```
("#datePicker").datepicker();
```

but that doesn't work for me either (Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker').

Thanks

Comment: did you load the jquery ui javascript file??

Comment: @Ehtesham Yes. I can use the jquery ui date picker just fine if I add the elements right to the <div> in the page, instead of trying to do it on page load.

Comment: the ID you used is datePicker (note the capital P) but in your jquery above you use ("#datepicker") (with a lowercase p).

Comment: @Mystere Man Sorry, that was a typo on my part while posting my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason it isn't working for you is because the input field you're binding the datepicker isn't available on document ready.

You need to bind the date picker after you've added the markup to the DOM.

[Check out this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p5nB5/)

Adding the datepicker after you've this line should work

```
$("#contentDiv").html(innerHtml);
$('#datePicker').datepicker();
```

Comment: Completely correct.  I can't believe how long I've been looking at this and didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery built-in functions has no calendar function. So, You've to import a plugin. There's a lot of them:

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2011/10/jquery-calendar-date-pickers.html

But, perhaps the most used is the jQuery UI cause it has a lot more function:

http://jqueryui.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could use this: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/
for creating datepicker

Answer (score 0):

all you need is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

and in the form :

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker"></p>
```

this will use the Jquery UI and create a datepicker for every input field with datepicker as class

Comment: Problem still persists, trying to create this on page load causes it to not load, but having it in the page to start works just fine.